# Frequently Answered Questions (by topic)

Tags: discussion, faq

**Members are welcome to continue to directly edit this FAQ**

Note The [Help Page](http://money.stackexchange.com/help) shows a link to this FAQ

If you missed it, please read the [Code of Conduct](https://money.stackexchange.com/conduct) along with the [Official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)

#### [Getting Started](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starting-out-investing) [starting-out-investing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starting-out-investing)

- [Best way to start investing, for a young person just starting their career?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/1625)
- [Oversimplify it for me: the correct order of investing](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/47856)

#### [Sudden Wealth/Windfall](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/15784)

- [What to do with sudden wealth?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/15784)

#### [Scams](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams) [scams](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams)

- [Most common types of financial scams an individual investor should beware of?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/654)
- [Is this person wanting to pay my credit card trying to defraud me?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/84251)
- [I received $1000 and was asked to send it back. How was this scam meant to work?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/68110)
- [Scam or Real: A woman from Facebook apparently needs my bank account to send money](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/67941)

#### [Credit](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit) [credit](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit) [credit-card](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-card)

- [If I were to buy something a day before my due date for my credit card bill, would I be charged interest?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/49525)
- [Is it worth it to take a car loan to improve credit ratings?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/74203)
- [Do people tend to spend less when using cash than credit cards?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/83755)
- [Should I open a credit card when I turn 18 just to start a credit score?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48490)
- [How much does credit score matter?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/59243)

#### [Mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage) [mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage)

- A US based question would be about down payments, PMI, and gift/loan
- [How big of a mortgage can I realistically afford?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/9035)
- [How to shop for mortgage rates ?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/47905) [In the U.S.]
- [How to avoid having my father's down payment assistance get taxed as a gift](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/14401)
- [After hitting 80% LTV, my mortgage lender refuses to remove PMI. Any recourse?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/44967)
- [15 year mortgage vs 30 year paid off in 15](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/43231)

#### [Buy vs Rent](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rent) [rent](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rent)

- [The balance between Renting and Buying](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/114737)
- [When is it better to rent and when is better buy in a certain property market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/3565)
- [In general, is it financially better to buy or to rent a house?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2075)
- [Why is the "buy vs rent" debate framed in terms of "buy a house vs. rent an apartment"?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/105495)
- [Is there any reason to not buy if mortgage is comparable to rent?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/129495)
- [How high does the buy-to-rent ratio have to be to make renting cheaper over the long term?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/108773)

#### [Insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insurance) [insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insurance)

- [Why should I invest my money in a life insurance policy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/1176) [term vs whole life]

#### [Stocks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stocks) [stocks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stocks)

- [What is the meaning of "short selling" or "going short" a stock?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/695)
- [If a stock doesn't pay dividends, then why is the stock worth anything?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/51976)
- [Wash Sale Question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135030) (example of wash sale rule)

#### [Mutual Fund Investments](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-funds) [mutual-funds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutual-funds)

- [Mutual fund value went down, shares went up, no action taken by me](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/41522)
- [Why are daily rebalanced inverse/leveraged ETFs bad for long term investing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/69879)

#### [Gold](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gold) [gold](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gold)

- [Why does gold have value?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/1767)
- [How do you measure the value of gold?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/9230)
- [Does gold's value decrease over time due to the fact that it is being continuously mined?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/10013)
- [Is physical gold inflation-proof?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/14859)

#### [Money transfer to and from India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) [india](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india)

- [US Salary Transfered to Indian Acc and Tax Relation](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/57106)
- [Transferring money from Foreign Account to NRO Account in india - is it taxable?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/55024)
- [Can I transfer money from an NRE account to a USA checking account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/29961)
- [How to transfer inheritance money from India to USA](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/71951)

#### [How to calculate interest rates](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apr) [apr](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apr)

#### [Loan amortization](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amortization) [amortization](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amortization)

- [Why do banks want you to pay off interest before principal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/22315)

#### [Retirement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retirement) [retirement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retirement)

- [What happens to people without any retirement savings?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/79065)

#### [IRA](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ira) [ira](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ira)

- Suggested topics:

  - Can I deduct my contribution
  - [What are the differences between a "traditional" IRA and a Roth IRA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/5)
  - Required Minimum Distribution

#### [401(k)](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ira) [401k](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/401k)

- [Recent graduate with new job: Choose Roth 401(k), or traditional 401(k)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/1598)
- [Are 401(k) contribution limits for employee & employer separate? What about hitting the limit?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/12752)
- [401(k) Contribution When Employer Has No Match?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/8634)
- Roth vs regular vs post-tax
- Rollover (Should I?, how?)
- [Why would you not want to rollover a previous employer's 401(k) when changing jobs?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/22829)
- 401(k) loan provisions (length, amount, drawbacks, benefits)

Comment: (Could this post be featured so it appears in the sidebar of the main site? Adding the 'featured' tag could effect that.)

Comment: It was for a while. Added it back now. Thx.