# Canonical: "I am X but I want a expensive car" question

Tags: discussion, questions

It seems like we have a fair few similar questions.
They are all something like:
Asker says they are not wealthy, but they want an expensive car.
Then they say something about their finances, and the price of the car.
That bit differs but not by enough.

They likely know in their heart that it is unwise to buy such a car,
and thus are asking here, hoping to be "given permission".
The answers are all: "No, thats unwise"

- [By 18 years of age, I want a brand new car that's $43,668](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99097/by-18-years-of-age-i-want-a-brand-new-car-thats-43-668)
- [Buying a brand new luxury car](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99620/buying-a-brand-new-luxury-car?rq=1)
- [Buying my first car out of college](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/buying-my-first-car-out-of-college?rq=1)
- [Buying new car at 18](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/119120/buying-new-car-at-18)

I am wondering if we should write 1 slightly more general canonical question, then close all future such questions as duplications

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest choosing the highest voted answer of these, and using it as a target of "closed as duplicate" for new identical questions. No need to create a somewhat fake new Q&A to address this.

We've been here before with the scam topic, and more recently, the sugar daddy questions. 
I'd also consider adding that top one to [the FAQ](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/frequently-answered-questions-by-topic).

I'm a bit surprised the recent ones haven't been closed as duplicate by members.